# Why figure number is not known in scientific word?

Tags: captions, scientific-workplace

I am using the scientific word to write my document. I inserted a photo with .tif format. In its properties, Labeling> Key, I have entered "fig:path" and use it for cross-referencing. However, for the first photo, the number 1.1 appears and it seems that it is section number and photo number. However, for the second photo, its number is 2. Moreover, in the caption of the photo the word Figure 1/2/.. is not shown.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you save your code as "portable latex" and post it here?

Comment: The most common source for this problem is that `\label` has to go *after* `\caption`.

Comment: I am using Scientific Word and I think it should automatically insert the label and caption in the right place. I dont know why the "Floating" in 'Layout' is not active and I cannot click on it? Is there any relationship between this and the issue that the figure has no number?
Moreover, I can exclude the section number in the numbering of tables and figures?